# How to get the next month in PHP

Tags: php

I need to get the next month with php.  Everywhere is written these example

```php
date('Y-m-t', strtotime('+1 month'));
```

The output of the above code is `'2017-03-31'`. I need to get February, not March.

Comment: ("03" is march, not may.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to get the next irrespective of the current date in the current month. below code may help you

```
echo date('M',strtotime('first day of +1 month'));
// e.g. "Jan"

echo date('m',strtotime('first day of +1 month'));
// e.g. "1"

echo date('F',strtotime('first day of +1 month'));
// e.g. "January"
```

This will give you Next month.

You can find more formatting masks in [`date()` function documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#example-2063)

Comment: For now it's resulting "Apr"

Comment: For now it's resulting "Jul"

Comment: Use lowercase "m" to get 4 or 7, instead "Apr" or "Jul".

Comment: Additional info: without 'first day of' you can get unexpected results. For instance today is 31-08-2021. `date('Y-m', strtotime("-2 months"));` returns '2021-07', but you expect '2021-06'.

Comment: For now it's resulting "Sep"

Answer (score 10):

Use Like This

```
// One month from today
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));

// One month from a specific date
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime('2015-01-01')));
```

Comment: This might not work as expected everyday: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime('2020-08-31')))` yields `2020-10-01`, so its skipping the month of september when called on the last day of august. The accepted solution does not have this problem.

Comment: im currently using a similar solution and it has an issue when its the end of the month as @MaPePeR mentioned. will update mine to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the code below to get the next months first day.

```
$date = (new \DateTime('first day of next month'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

This is safer than 'next month' or '+1 month' because you may skip some months then.

Answer (score 3):

To get next month using php use string to time function as below:

```
$nxtm = strtotime("next month");
echo date("M", $nxtm);
```

Answer (score 1):

date("m", strtotime("2021-08-16 +1 Month"));

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the next month with the same day as this month, or the last day of the next month if it otherwise would switch month you can use this function

```
function nextMonth()
{
    $nextMonthNumber = date('M', strtotime('first day of +1 month'));
    $nextMonthDate = new DateTime();
    $nextMonthDate->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    while ($nextMonthDate->format('M') != $nextMonthNumber) {
        $nextMonthDate->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    return $nextMonthDate;
}
```