# Modify DateTime instance to next month

Tags: php, datetime

Given a `DateTime` instance initialized as :

```
$tgtDateDT = new DateTime('now');
```

which for example equates to `2023-01-30` when formatted as `->format("Y-m-d")`,

I want to advance the month to February (for rendering a calendar) where I was hoping to do:

```
$nextMonth = $tgtDateDT->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```

Which when formatted with `->format("Y-m-d")` yields

```
2023-03-02
```

So February has 28 days so I understand it may yield an unpredictable result.

So how can I take a date from any day in one month and advance it to say "the first" of the next month - preferably with `DateInterval`.

For my calendar rendering the new date can be any day in the next month.

Comment: Consider https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/, which is widely used and has things like `startOfMonth()` implemented.

Comment: You should first very strictly define what you mean by "a month" and what moving a date forward by that interval _means_ with regard to your intended implementation and/or business case. ISO8601's `P1M` is one very specific case of "a month" that evidently does not fit your needs/expectations.

Comment: Do check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13422716/7224159

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the next month in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952314/how-to-get-the-next-month-in-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given any day in a month and needing to advance to the first day of the next month (such as flipping to next month on a calendar) the following can be performed:

```
$tgtDateDT = new DateTime('now');
// implement "startOfMonth"
$tgtDateDT->setDate($tgtDateDT->format('Y'), $tgtDateDT->format('m'),1);
$tgtDateDT->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
printf ($tgtDateDT);
```

So `2023-01-30` yields `2023-02-01`.